# Zfs: initramfs cannot import rpool in new computer

Tags: boot, initramfs, zfs

I'm trying to migrate to a new laptop, and I placed my nvme ssd with Ubuntu 20.04 in the new laptop, but now it's not seeing my rpool for some reason. I'm really not sure why (it's on the same nvme ssd).

Here's the error message:

[image: spool initramfs error message]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to boot the nvme ssd, and thought I should post the solution in case someone else had the same problem

Since secure boot was enabled when I installed Ubuntu, it had to be enabled on the new laptop before rpool would mount.  This involves finding the setting in the BIOS and enabling it, which requires also disabling any legacy boot capabilities.

On the Dell Precision 7730, secure boot was a little difficult to actually enable.  It wasn't until I opened the boot menu I realized secure boot wasn't actually enabled, even though I had enabled the setting in the BIOS.

I had to go back into the BIOS menu, delete the secure boot keys, and reset secure boot before it would register as being enabled with the new nvme ssd.

If you're still having trouble getting rpool to mount, check the boot menu (F12 at startup) and see if it says secure boot is enabled or not.  You can attempt to enable it from the boot menu - if it's not possible, try deleting the keys and resetting it.